# Perform Sum of Multiple Textfields in array on runtime using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple textfields with same name.

When someone types a number in one of textfield. It should show sum on runtime in Sum Textfield.

Can anyone help me with that?

I have this HTML:

```
<table width="400" border="1" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">
    SUM: 
    <input type="text" name="sum" id="sum" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="textfield" id="field_1" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="textfield" id="field_2" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="textfield" id="field_3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="textfield" id="field_4" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is my Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/36Yhe/1/

Comment: @DSG Basically I dont have a logic for this

Comment: Thats *very* invalid HTML. Replace those criminally same ids to classes or something pls.

Comment: @anand4tech Check my post now. I have edited it

Comment: @techfoobar Please check it now

Comment: @CodeHunter - Thats muuch better..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
// selects all inputs but "#sum"
var inputs = $('input:not(#sum)');
// each time the user releases a key
inputs.keyup(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    // loops through every inputs
    inputs.each(function () {
        // parses input's value into a float
        // if parsing fails uses 0 instead of NaN (NaN || 0)
        sum += parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0;
    });
    // displays the result
    $('#sum').val(sum);
});
```

Here is a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/8K24v/.

---

Another (twisted) solution :

```
var inputs = $('input:not(#sum)');
inputs.keyup(function () {
    $('#sum').val(new Function('return ' + inputs.map(function () {
        return parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0;
    }).get().join('+') + ';')());
});
```

And its (twisted) demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/sraV3/.

Let's unroll the twisted part :

1. `inputs.map(...).get()` : Turns a jQuery list of inputs into an array of numbers.
2. `.join('+')` : Turns the array of numbers into a string. Example : `[1,2].join('+')` gives `"1+2"`.
3. `new Function('return ...;')()` : Creates a new function and executes it immediately. At this point we have something like : `new Function('return 1+1+1+1;')()` (evaluate this code into your browser console, the output is obviously the number 4).
4. Finally, the result of this function is passed to `$('#sum').val(...)`.

---

Additional contents :

- http://api.jquery.com/map/
- http://api.jquery.com/get/
- [MDN : Array join method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- [MDN : Function (constructor)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)
- [MDN : parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

Comment: @CodeHunter I've added some explanations. Let me know if you're still in trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Using vanilla JavaScript you can do it like this:

```
(function () {
    var textFields = document.getElementsByName('textfield');

    sum = function() {
        var sum = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < textFields.length; i++) {
            var val = textFields[i].value;
            if (parseFloat(val) == val) {
                sum += parseFloat(val);
            }
        }
        document.getElementById('sum').value = sum;
    };

    document.getElementById('sum-table').addEventListener("keyup", sum, false);

    sum();
})();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HEvb8/1/)

Also your element **IDs** should be unique where as the name can be the same. I have shown this in the above fiddle.

*Edited, with updated fiddle, to include changes suggested by @bfontaine*

Comment: You should use only one listener on the table instead of one per field (1000 fields = 1000 listeners instead of only one).

Comment: A further update can be found here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HEvb8/2/) which gives full browser support to the **Event Listener**.